# Filtering js array with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, underscore.js

I'm new to Java Script and completely not into front end. I have a problem how to display filtered array in html template. 
What I have is:

```
 <form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input v-model="stitle" type="text" id=inputTitle/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input v-model="scast" type="text" id="inputCast"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input @click="messageFiltering" type="button" class="btn btn-info col-sm-12" value="Szukaj"/>
    </div>
  </form>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Production Year</th>
        <th>Cast</th>
        <th>Genres</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="movie in messageFiltering">
            <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
            <td>{{movie.year}}</td>
            <td>{{movie.cast.toString()}}</td>
            <td>{{movie.genres.toString()}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And my script:

```
  <script type="module">
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    stitle: '',
    syearfrom: '',
    syearto: '',
    scast: '',
    movies: [
      {"title":"Chained for Life","year":1951,"cast":["Hilton Twins"],"genres":[]},
      {"title":"Cheese Chasers","year":1951,"cast":["Looney Tunes"],"genres":["Animated"]},
      {"title":"Chicago Calling","year":1951,"cast":["Dan Duryea","Mary Anderson"],"genres":["Noir"]},
      {"title":"China Corsair","year":1951,"cast":["Jon Hall","Ernest Borgnine"],"genres":["Adventure"]},
      {"title":"So This Is Paris","year":1955,"cast":["Tony Curtis","Gloria DeHaven"],"genres":["Musical"]},
      {"title":"Soldier of Fortune","year":1955,"cast":["Clark Gable","Susan Hayward"],"genres":["Drama"]},
      {"title":"Son of Sinbad","year":1955,"cast":["Dale Robertson","Sally Forrest","Vincent Price"],"genres":["Adventure"]},
      {"title":"Southbound Duckling","year":1955,"cast":["Tom and Jerry"],"genres":["Animated"]},
      {"title":"Special Delivery","year":1955,"cast":["Joseph Cotten","Eva Bartok"],"genres":["Comedy"]}
      ],
  },

    methods: {
        messageFiltering() {
            let collection = _.filter(movies, function (element) {
                return element.year.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.syearfrom.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1;
            });

            collection = _.filter(collection, function (element) {
                return element.title.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.stitle.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1;
            });

            collection = _.filter(collection, function (element) {
                return element.cast.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.scast.toLowerCase().toLowerCase()) != -1;
            });
            return collection;
        }
    }
})
```

I would like to display the array movies filtered by messageFiltering() by the user input from form in my table But I have no idea how to connect it. Is the button `@click` event alright?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish, just shorten your code first. Secondaly, You do not need lodash for this basic filter, you can use default [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do this task.
Also there seems to be multiple toLowerCase() instead of toString().toLowerCase()

```
collection = _.filter(collection, function (element) {
                return element.cast.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.scast.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1;
            });
            return collection;
```

Maybe this helps you, if not please edit the question so that we could understand it better what you want to accomplish and not this redundant code.

Just refactoring your code method

```
messageFiltering() {
            return movies.filter(movies, function (element) {
                return element.year.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.syearfrom.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1 && element.title.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.stitle.toString().toLowerCase()) != -1 && element.cast.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.scast.toStringe().toLowerCase()) != -1;
            });
        }
```

Edit   :
Try updating this line

```
<input v-on:click="messageFiltering" type="button" class="btn btn-info col-sm-12" value="Szukaj"/>
```

[Ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Comment: I edited the question an cut off some html. Unfortuntely, I have to use underscore. What I need is to display the array that messageFiltering() will give me in the html table section. I added the message to click in button, but don't know how to connect it to the <td> in table and v-for.

Comment: Alternatively try throwing in console in the method or set break point there and check whether it gets triggered or not, I have never done Vue in my life, this is my knowledge of js

Comment: do you know how to connect the outcome of messageFiltering() with <td> in <table>  to desplay the filtered movies?